# Talking to a PHP Daemon

Tags: php, daemon

I'm developing a small server daemon in php that will communicate with various remote clients - simple enough. However, another daemon running on the same machine will need to communicate with the first, as fast as possible but may be sending several hundred KB's of data constantly (hopefully within 20 HTZ). I'm pretty positive I'll want to use a tcp connection between these two daemons, but that's where I need some advice. Now before you ask, the reason I can't simply combine both into the same daemon is because the second can and will be written in one of multiple languages including java, .net, c++, python, ruby, etc. If there's a way to make PHP talk to another language without using a tcp connection (or using a system call which wouldn't work for my needs) and without sacrificing performance, I'm all ears but I've been search for a way to do this and I can't really find a clean, simple way of doing it - at least not on a "one sized fits all" fashion.

Comment: Unix-domain sockets will always be faster than TCP ones. Don't use tcp for local-only communications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the other process will be on the same machine, how about using [`proc_open()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), then you just write/read from the pipes (stdin/stdout etc) created?

It's similar to a [`system()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)/[`popen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) call, but it allows you to read and write to the other process, and of course the overhead of the TCP socket is avoided.

Comment: Awesome! I'll give that a try..do you think this will work well even if I'm peaking at around say 1MB of data in a single write/read operation?

Comment: @Xealgo yes, no problem - communication via UNIX sockets (pipes) is very very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sockets. PHP has a socket implementation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php

I have only really done socket programming in C, but most of the other languages you have listed should be able to work with sockets just fine.

In PHP, you would use `socket_bind()` to connect to the socket. Likewise, you will need to do the equivalent on the other daemon.

Comment: I already have been working a bit with this but thanks for you're post anyway!